# Is it possible to connect to queries but get the results of first query before second one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select users from my db based on their interests and country and then i want to select them based on interests only.So here is my queries

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
JOIN user_opt ON users.id = user_opt.UserId 
WHERE user_opt.country IN(".implode(',',$Countries).")  AND user_opt.Hobbies REGEXP '".implode('|',$Interests)."'  LIMIT 100

SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
JOIN user_opt ON users.id = user_opt.UserId WHERE user_opt.country IN(".implode(',',$Countries).")  LIMIT 100
```

Now i want to join them into one query,but get the results of first query before second one's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all` and `order by` if you want to guarantee that the first results come before the second:

```
(SELECT u.* , 1 as which
 FROM users u JOIN
      user_opt uo
      ON u.id = uo.UserId 
 WHERE u.country IN (".implode(',',$Countries).")  AND
       uo.Hobbies REGEXP '".implode('|',$Interests)."' 
 LIMIT 100
) UNION ALL
(SELECT u.*, 2 as which
 FROM users u JOIN
      user_opt uo
      ON u.id = uo.UserId
 WHERE uo.country IN(".implode(',',$Countries).") 
 LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY which;
```

Comment: Thanks for thy heuristic answer

Answer (score 0):

One probably solution can be

```
select * from 
    (select 1 AS sn, users.*
       ...
     union
     select 2 AS sn, users.*
       ...)
   order by sn;
```

Comment: what is sn my beloved friend?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso `sn` can be used to differentiate, from which part of the union, data is coming, is it coming from upper select or lower select